# How to fix jquery .is(':focus') not responding

Tags: javascript

I'm making an if statement but it doesn't seem to work. I think it has to do with the :focus (jquery is implemented)

I tried using $("input:focus") but when I pressed enter anywhere, (focused or not) it shows the alert.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

<body style="background-color: #90EE90;">

    <center>
        Sample text
        <br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="user-input" placeholder="insert name">
        <br><br>

    </center>
    <script>

        var input = $('#user-input').val();

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).keypress(function (key) {
                if (key.which === 13 && $('#user-input').is(':focus')) {
                    alert("hello");
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

When I press enter while user-input is highlighted, it should've gave the Hello alert, but instead, nothing happens.

Comment: You select the input element with `$('#user-input')`, but the element does not have an id.

Answer (score 0):

change `name="user-input"` to `id="user-input"`